# Randomly rotate image from its last position with CSS3

Tags: javascript, animation, random, css, rotation

I'd like to have a "Wheel of Fortune" effect. When user clicks the image, it rotates random degrees (between 180-540 degrees) from its last position. Rotation should be done with CSS3. Here's my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#pic {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin
{
100% {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(300deg);}
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function animRes() {
  var $element = $("#pic").bind("webkitAnimationEnd", function(){
    this.style.webkitAnimationName = "";
  });
}
function doSpin() {
  animRes();
  $("#pic").css('-webkit-animation', 'spin 1s ease-out');
  $("#pic").css('-webkit-animation-fill-mode', 'forwards'); //doesn't work when using AnimRes()
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="pic" src="picture.jpg" alt="pic" onclick="doSpin();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Problems are:
How to randomly change the value of rotation in keyframes?
How to continue rotation from its last position?

At the moment animRes() is reseting animation so the `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards` doesn't work but without animRes() I can't reset the animation for more spins. Writing the answer with jQuery and plain JS is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get into some math to achieve what you want to do, hopefully it's not too difficult to understand...

```
var degrees=0, seconds=0, previousRotation=0;

$("#spinner").click(function(){
 previousRotation = degrees;
 degrees+= parseInt(Math.random() * 360 + 180);
  //you should adjust this formula
   miliseconds = parseInt((degrees - previousRotation)) * 5;
    $(this).css({
        "-webkit-transform" : "rotate("+ degrees +"deg)",
        "-webkit-transition-duration" : miliseconds + "ms"
    });
});
```

I'm using CSS Transitions instead of animations because they are more simple.

The miliseconds = ... formula makes the transition last longer if there's more degrees to be transitioned. Hopefully you can integrate all of this into the code you already wrote.

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/XkNrf/

Comment: This is perfect for my needs. Took a while to understand it but I do now :) Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't process this way.

I made a little example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5qSZw/2/)

It uses -moz properties, but they all have a webkit equivalent, so it should be fine.

The idea is the following: your image is rotating in an infinite fashion BUT is paused most of the time ([using `-moz-animation-play-state`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-play-state.asp). When the user click it, it starts running. A random number is generated between a and b. And then it rotates for X*Y+Z milliseconds (in the example a and b have a 1 and 11 value, and Y is 1000, Z is 0) then it pauses again.

This way you can customize easily the number of possible outcomes and the minimum rotation time.

And you can also store the current value with an external variable starting at 0 and that's incremented by X each time an user click.

Comment: Thank you for your help and quick reply! Good way to approach this problem. However, I would like to use timing functions on every new spin to make the spinning more realistic. It should have fast start and then slow down towards the end.

Comment: This might be hard to do with css alone. Have you considered using canvas? If you want, you can try to use rapahel.js. With the combination of the image, rotate and animate, it should be allright. See http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html for the doc.

Comment: I'll take a look at it. I need to have CSS3 animations because I need this to work smoothly on iPad also. I have tried out Raphael.js long time ago but I can't remember were the animations smooth on iPad or not. I'll check that.